# "Vapid public key must be a URL safe Base 64" web-push error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-push

I faced to a error from web-push library in my nodejs backend app.
When I want to set public key and private key in web-push with webpush.setVapidDetails()
I received an error in my terminal that said: "Error: Vapid public key must be a URL safe Base 64"
Please help me to fix it.

```
    webpush.setVapidDetails(
    "mailto:example@example.com",
    process.env.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY,
    process.env.VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY
    );
```

and I tried to use some different ways for example:

```
    const publicKey = base64url.toBase64(process.env.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY);
    const privateKey = base64url.toBase64(process.env.VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: since `base64url.toBase64` converts *a base64url encoded string to a base64 encoded string* you're probably doing it wrong - as you don't want base64, you want base64url

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your tips. I write this function:

 function stringToBase64Url(input) {
    // Replace non-URL compatible characters with standard Base64 characters
    const base64 = Buffer.from(input).toString('base64')

    // Remove trailing equal signs
    return base64.replace(/=+$/m, "");
  }

but I received an error again.

Comment: why not just use `base64url.fromBase64` since you already include the base64url library? your function only removes trailing `=` ... that's not enough to make url safe base64 - also, if your env values are already base64, then `Buffer.from(input).toString('base64')` will just make base64 OF the base64!

Comment: or you could just `Buffer.from(input, "base64").toString("base64url");` of course - again, I'm assuming that `process.env.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY` and `process.env.VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY` are base64 encoded - only you can know that though

Comment: @JaromandaX I received an error again.

Comment: oh no, I can't see what the error is, since you haven't answered any of my questions regarding the current encoding of those keys, you're on your own